# Extraneous `<head>` in spec / capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in one of my rails 6 controller I'm using

`render html: "<html><body id='my_callback'>...</html>`

and spec:

`expect(page.body).to eq("<html><body id='my_callback'...`

I'm using capybara/rspec/chrome for system tests and I get a failure due to something injecting a `<head>` attribute:

`got: "<html><head></head><body id=\"my_callback\">...`

what is adding this tag? rails, capybara or chrome?